# Can Tension between two blocks on a horizontal plane be discovered in these conditions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

- the bodies are linked by an ideal string, one has m1=10kg & the other m2=20kg
- The force is known and is pulling horizontally, F=60N on the lighter object
- the coefficient of friction is said to be the same for both objects
- it is not specified if the bodies are moving with constant velocity

I can't find the acceleration without the coefficient of friction or vice versa.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Jimnosperm a=2m/s-u*10 u= the coefficient of friction

(m1+m2)a=[F-u*g(m1+m2)]

Comment: You're approaching it the wrong way. Try looking at each block individually and solve for the tension that way. I assure you the problem is solvable.

Comment: @Jimnosperm, I think I did it, T=2F/3, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$m_1 = m = 10$ kg

$m_2 = 2m_1 = 20$ kg

$F = 60$ N;

$ma = F - \mu mg-T$

$2ma = T - 2\mu m g$

$\Rightarrow ma+\mu mg = F-T$

$ 2(m a+ \mu mg)=T$

$\Rightarrow 1/2=(F-T)/T \Rightarrow T = 2F/3$